# SignIn With Apple "invalid_client" error Asp.Net Core token request

Tags: c#, jwt, key, openid-connect, apple-id

I`m trying to implement Sign In With Apple in my Asp.Net Core application using OpenIdConnect client library. With help of this article https://www.scottbrady91.com/openid-connect/implementing-sign-in-with-apple-in-aspnet-core. Everything works fine when I create application in apple console https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers. But when I create another application (and service identifier with corresponding key) the new application doesnt work.

1. [Create App ID with signin with apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIw4X.png)
2. [with Sign In With Apple enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CtES.png)
3. Creating service identifier with Sign In With Apple enabled
4. Create key for this app
5. Use this key for client_secret generation

If I create another app/serviceId/key it doesnt work untill I revoke key for first app and create new key for new app.

How can I create two working apps? I there any restriction?

Adding "apple" external provider:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("apple", async options =>
            {
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token"; // hybrid flow due to lack of PKCE support
                options.ResponseMode = "form_post"; // form post due to prevent PII in the URL
                options.UsePkce = false; // apple does not currently support PKCE (April 2021)
                options.DisableTelemetry = true;

                options.Scope.Clear(); // apple does not support the profile scope
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("name");

                options.Authority = "https://appleid.apple.com";
                options.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Apple:ClientId"]; // Service ID
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-apple";

                options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                {
                    context.TokenEndpointRequest.ClientSecret = AppleTokenGenerator.CreateNewToken(configuration["Authentication:Apple:Iss"],configuration["Authentication:Apple:ClientId"], configuration["Authentication:Apple:ClientSecret"]);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

               

                // TODO
            })
```

Generating client_secret as described in https://www.scottbrady91.com/openid-connect/implementing-sign-in-with-apple-in-aspnet-core.:

```
public static string CreateNewToken(string iss, string sub, string privateKey)
        {
            const string aud = "https://appleid.apple.com";
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            
            var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create();
            ecdsa?.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey), out _);

            var handler = new JsonWebTokenHandler();
            return handler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Issuer = iss,
                Audience = aud,
                Claims = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "sub", sub } },
                Expires = now.AddMinutes(60), // expiry can be a maximum of 6 months - generate one per request or re-use until expiration
                IssuedAt = now,
                NotBefore = now.AddMinutes(-60),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa), SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256)
            });
        }
```

Authorization request works fine. No errors and redirecting browser to `options.CallbackPath = "/signin-apple";`

Error occures on token request: `OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.`

I`ve simulated request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=ua.secret.site&code=c3a55f910698647768b41e76a80881778.0.rwqy.Pt5lhGYR0eKHHmIOhsrkrw&redirect_uri=https://local.test:5001/signin-apple&client_secret=eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1YS5zZWNyZXQuc2l0ZSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBwbGVpZC5hcHBsZS5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2NTQwOTg2NjYsImlzcyI6IjdCNjREQzJYUE4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTQwOTUwNjYsIm5iZiI6MTY1NDA5MTQ2Nn0.PkaPgnCF4u53w9yZgRXqmJ1xyN2DhTIukoknvRQ0jLfU4riVEUqPwh5c0Umx_cteadrcTjID-J_iH3hFPxUTrA'
```

and getting this response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

with no usefull response headers

But with another client everything is ok
[image]

Also I`ve made experiment releasing and revoking keys for two different applications (t - testing app, p - production app).
Here is the result:

[image]

Conclusion:
Only one of two keys is working at a time, despite being created for diferent applications. Keys are being invalidated acording to key rotation rules for SINGLE application (https://help.apple.com/developer-account/?lang=en#/dev77c875b7e), but sometimes NOT.
I`am so confused.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue, @Anton?

Answer (score 0):

The magic was to add this

```
SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa){KeyId = keyId},
SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256)
```

It works fine when there is one key, but if there are multiple, I guess it uses the last key for validation.
You need to add `keyId` for Apple to recognize the key for validation.